# Getting started with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I didn't find any good documentation for getting started with the Ember.js. Please help me,
Here is a simple example i tried from http://emberjs.com/documentation/ But nothing displayed on screen.

```
Error:  MyApp is not defined
```

Javascript: app.js

```
    MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create({
  firstName: "Barack",
  lastName: "Obama",
  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  // Tell Ember that this computed property depends on firstName
  // and lastName
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

HTML

```
<p>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  The President of the United States is {{MyApp.president.fullName}}.
</script>
</p>
```

I included all the JS files from the getting started Kit.

Comment: "I didn't find any good documentation" ???  Have you looked at http://emberjs.com/documentation/ ?

Comment: Yes, But, the example in documentation didn't work. see my code

Comment: Ooops, sorry.  Se my answer

Comment: Hum, http://emberjs.com/guides/application/ seems to explain that, does'nt it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've forgot to define MyApp, which has to be an instance of Ember.Application:

```
var MyApp = Ember.Application.create({});
```

Here is one very comprehensive tutorial I've found few weeks ago, maybe it would be useful for your learning purposes: http://www.appliness.com/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-ember-js/

Answer (score 4):

You have to define `MyApp`

I have created a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wqhwn/139/). Click the **Run** button to see the result.

**HTML**

```
<p>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  The President of the United States is {{MyApp.president.fullName}}.
</script>
</p>​
```

**Code**

```
window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create({
  firstName: "Barack",
  lastName: "Obama",
  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
​
```